# Cannot create injector for Guava Service Manager in Dropwizard application

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guava, guice, dropwizard

I want to use Guava's Service Manager to manage services in my Dropwizard application.

`ServiceManagerProvider` provides the service manager:

```
@Singleton
public class ServiceManagerProvider implements Provider<ServiceManager> {
    @Inject
    Set<Service> services;

    public static Multibinder<Service> serviceRegistry(Binder binder) {
        return Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder, Service.class);
    }

    @Override
    public ServiceManager get() {
        return new ServiceManager(services);
    }
}
```

`ManagedGuavaServices` is a `Managed` object that interacts with the Service Manager to start/stop services:

```
public class ManagedGuavaServices implements Managed {
    @Inject
    private ServiceManager _serviceManager;

    @Inject
    public ManagedGuavaServices(ServiceManager serviceManager) {
        _serviceManager = serviceManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        _serviceManager.startAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        _serviceManager.stopAsync();
    }
}
```

`MyModule` is the module where the Guice bindings are specified:

```
public class MyModule extends DropwizardAwareModule<MyConfig> {
  ...
  @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(ServiceManager.class).toProvider(ServiceManagerProvider.class);
      bind(Managed.class).to(ManagedGuavaServices.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

And `MyApplication` is the Dropwizard application that depends on `MyModule`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application<MyConfig> {
  @Inject
  private Managed managedServices;

  ...

  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfig> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(GuiceBundle.builder()
                .printDiagnosticInfo()
                .printGuiceBindings()
                .enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
                .modules(
                        new MyModule()
                )
                .build());
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public void run(MyConfig config, Environment environment) {
    environment.lifecycle().manage(managedServices);
  }
}
```

It seems like everything has been wired together, but when I run the application, I get the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at io.dropwizard.lifecycle.setup.LifecycleEnvironment.manage(LifecycleEnvironment.java:45)
    at com.example.MyApplication.run(MyApplication.java:188)
    at com.example.MyApplication.run(MyApplication.java:60)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
    at com.example.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.webobjects._bootstrap.WOBootstrap.main(WOBootstrap.java:118)
```

which essentially means that the injected `managedServices` in `MZPaymentApplication` is null when the application is run.

What is wrong here? Is it the same problem as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213584/inject-field-is-always-null)? If so, where should the `@PostConstruct` be?

Comment: Please, provide full error log with full stacktrace.

Comment: Also, I believe that the problem may be in being `managedServices` field in `Application` not injectable, since app object is not configured by Guice (I guess you create it via `new` keyword?). So you should store you GuiceBundle instance in `initialize` method as field and then access any Guice binding in `run` method with `guiceBundle.getInjector().getInstance()`

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk Yup, the application is create via `new`: `new MyApplication().run(args);` in the `main` method. Cool, let me give it a try.

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk You got it. Thanks so much for the help, if you write it up as an answer, I'll mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `managedServices` being field in Application and not injectable, since app object is not configured by Guice (usually in Dropwizard it is created via `new` keyword).
So you should store your `GuiceBundle` instance in `initialize` method as field and then access any Guice binding in `run` method with `guiceBundle.getInjector().getInstance()`, e.g.:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application<MyConfig> {

  private GuiceBundle<MyConfig> guiceBundle;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new MyApplication().run(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfig> bootstrap) {

    guiceBundle = GuiceBundle.builder()
                .printDiagnosticInfo()
                .printGuiceBindings()
                .enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
                .modules(
                        new MyModule()
                )
                .build();

    bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(MyConfig config, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    environment.lifecycle().manage(guiceBundle.getInjector().getInstance(Managed.class));
  }
}
```